# Determine third point of triangle when two points and two angles are known

Tags: trigonometry

There are some similar questions but not exactly as I have. I have 2 points (*x₁*,*y₁*) and (*x₂*,*y₂*), each has an angle *α₁* and *α₂* relative to the same angle
How would I with this information find the values (*x₃*,*y₃*) reliably regardless of position and angle?

**I have a working solution in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3k3t6zwxnc)**, however there *must* be a better way to do this.
I can only think to solve this by turning this into a triangle and then using one of the edges to form a right triangle and get offset from a known point for coordinates.
Or converting the points and angles into lines on a graph and solving for *x* then using that to get *y*, as shown in Desmos.

[image: illustration of exercise]

Comment: The tangent of the angles gives the slopes of the two sides. Given a point of a line and its slope you can find the equation. Given the equations of two non-parallel lines, you can find the point of intersection by finding the simultaneous solution of the two equations.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I have done that as shown in the Desmos link, but is that the correct solution? (also, I appreciate the edit)

Comment: Yes, your formula for $i$ gives the correct $x$ coordinate for the third vertex, so that looks correct.

Comment: Ok thank you, I just didn't know if I was overlooking something less messy